# Why shouldn't you update to the latest drivers on your OEM computer?

Tags: laptop, drivers, oem

I am in a bit of a debate with someone concerning the updating of OEM drivers.

Let's say you buy an Acer notebook which comes with pre-installed graphics drivers. One would argue that it's better to always run the latest drivers of AMD (or NVidia or Intel) to gain the best experience. However, I remember that this was discouraged by manufacturers and graphic card producers alike because the custom-build of the OEM (in this case Acer) might conflict with some of the properties in the newest driver. I.e. the message was "Use drivers that are approved by your notebook's manufacturer."

However, I can't seem to find such messages anywhere anymore. Not on NVidia's website, nor on AMD's and not even on Acer's support website. So what's happened?

- Should you always install the newest drivers for the components, even if it's an OEM machine?
- Why did they discourage you to do so a couple of years ago, but don't seem to do so any longer?

(If possible, provide sources of Nvidia, AMD or others)

Comment: IF the computer manufacturer was actually doing anything custom with the GPU then yes they would need to provide custom drivers and you would need to use those drivers. More than likely the interoperability of computer components has risen to a very functional and optimized level so why waste resources implementing custom solutions when the default config is basically "Good enough".

Comment: Nvidia releases its own drivers for its mobile products.  I have no idea if AMD does the same.  What you WILL NOT GET if you use Nvidia/AMD(s) drivers is the ability to switch between the Intel GPU and the Nvidia/AMD card in say a laptop.  The Nvidia/AMD drivers do not have this capability.  This functionality only exists with the OEM driver.  You might consider revising your question to limit the scope to display drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should you always install the newest drivers for the components, even if it's an OEM machine?

Yup, but really only if you're having problems.  Whenever I build new computers or reinstall the OS from scratch (personally or when I worked for an OEM) I always use the latest versions of the drivers from the manufacturers.

Get the latest ones offered for you specific model from the OEM, and then look for newer versions from the actual component's manufacturer.

> Why did they discourage you to do so a couple of years ago, but don't seem to do so any longer?

This was primarily seen in notebooks and other systems that required tight integration.

The (primary) reason they originally made you go to the OEM for certain drivers (usually video drivers) is because the OEMs would often implement the component in a specific way that worked (best) with their machine, and this often called for the OEM to modify the manufacturer's baseline driver.

Another reason was because often the OEMs buy the components from a manufacturer that doesn't provide end-user sales or support (at all, or for that model of the component).  So to use the component, the computer OEM had to take on the role of distributing the driver and providing support.

Again, it's hard to say WHY things have changed recently, and I can't even say for sure that it has, or if it just *seems* like it.

My guess would be that OEMs don't actually like investing in the resources required to keep customized drivers up-to-date for various components for many different models.  Since users keep computers for much longer than the OEM actively supports, over the years I have seen lots of complaints about how the OEM "refuses to" update their required custom drivers to support new feature/fix implemented by the manufacturer in the baseline driver, or to support new operating system versions, etc. Leading to unhappy customers.

So it's easier and cheaper for them to just use the product within the baseline specs, with the common/baseline driver.  They then don't need to bare the full responsibility for supporting the component's driver (if the manufacturer supplies one) and they also don't have to invest on-going resources into keeping it in-line with changes to the baseline driver, or update it to be compatible with newer OSs.

I would also think that years of this going on has caused the various component makers and the notebook OEMs to sit down and hammer out better interoperability guidelines so that the components (and drivers) work best "as-is", without modification.

Answer (score 1):

I should qualify this answer as being focused on **video drivers**.  For some reason, they seem to be in a class by themselves.  I have loaded device manufacturer drivers for other hardware without problems but video drivers are the bane of my existence.  Also, this answer is not meant to address a new or upgraded operating system, in which case new drivers may be necessary and they might need to come from the device manufacturer.

I agree with Techie007 that you should update only if you are having problems.  I disagree with him that when you do update, you should start with the latest device manufacturer drivers.  My recommendation is to use drivers from the device manufacturer only as a last resort.  This is based on a decade, including recent months, of experiencing problems with "retail" drivers on OEM equipment.  If the latest OEM driver is the same one you have and yours is corrupted, reload the OEM driver.

The device manufacturers update drivers for several reasons.  One is that bugs are discovered in the original driver.  These are usually discovered soon after release.  If your computer is more than a year old and you haven't encountered a bug that affected it from the beginning, the likelihood is  low that you need a bug fix.

Another reason for updates is to improve compatibility with specific new hardware or software.  If you don't have the hardware or software the update is designed for, you won't benefit from it.  If you do have that hardware or software and the OEM driver doesn't address the issue, try the device manufacturer's driver but be prepared to roll it back if you encounter new problems.

I have heard that occasionally, a driver update is designed to improve performance independent of other hardware or software.  I have never seen a significant performance improvement from a new driver in this context.  If you want to test it, just be prepared to roll it back if it introduces problems.

The chipset and circuitry on your motherboard doesn't change but the retail versions of the device hardware get improvements and new features.  The device manufacturers update drivers to incorporate those changes.  Your system won't benefit from those driver changes and it may make the driver incompatible with your OEM hardware.

The bottom line is that updated device manufacturer drivers rarely provide real performance improvement but often introduce problems that weren't there before.  If there is a specific reason to update, like compatibility problems with new hardware or software, that the OEM driver doesn't fix, then try the device manufacturer's driver.  Otherwise, go into the update recognizing that the device manufacturer's driver may not work.

In terms of the messaging being different now, I hadn't noticed that it was but I'll take your word for it.  There could be many reasons for the change that don't reflect changes in the technology, like marketing considerations.  I wouldn't draw any conclusions from such a messaging change.

Comment: An exception to the "don't update rule" might also be those touchpad drivers.  At least with Windows you need to keep those update if you migrate to a newer version of Windows than the laptop itself came with.